# How can I copy the change list to a text file using Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Is there any way I can copy the current change list to a text file in every commit?

I am using Mercurial HG, and an ASP.NET MVC and SQL-based web project. If this is possible, then I can always check the current change list by just checking the text file.

Any thoughts on this? Any other idea to achieve this?

Comment: What is a "change list"?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to get your question but I believe *patches* are what you're searching for.

You can create a patch in every source versioning software (hg/git/svn/etc.).

If you want to do that automatically on each commit, do a *hook* (this is also supported by all the source versioning softwares).

If you just want to check the changes, simply try the `diff` command (e.g., `hg diff`) that dumps the diff of the current changeset to the console. You can redirect it to a file too. There are some nice GUI tools for that (e.g., `git gui` for git).